# Mysql 5.5.38 ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '' for key 'anykey'

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.5, unique-constraint

I dropped my UNIQUE KEY index 'myindex' on a table
and I wanted to change the UNIQUE KEY to something else,
so after dropping it I did:

```
alter table mytable add unique key anykey (add1, city, state);
```

I now get the following message on a key that does not exist
(it doesnt seem to matter what key I change 'anykey' to, I always
get the same error:

```
ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '' for key 'anykey'
```

I dumped the entire DB and reloaded it, but still cannot seem to set
a unique key on 'mytable'.

Anyone know what I should check or how to get around this issue?
I WANT a unique key on this table.

The tables important parts:

```
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=3433 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

Thank you in advance for any help!

EDIT:  here's show create table

```
| mytable | CREATE TABLE `mytable` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`name_aka` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
`in_add1` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`in_add2` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`in_city` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`in_state` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
`in_zip` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
`in_zip4` varchar(4) NOT NULL,
`ship_add1` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`ship_add2` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`ship_city` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`ship_state` varchar(2) NOT NULL,
`ship_zip` varchar(5) NOT NULL,
`ship_zip4` varchar(4) NOT NULL,
`phone` varchar(14) NOT NULL,
`phoneExt` varchar(6) NOT NULL,
`phone2` varchar(14) NOT NULL,
`phone2Ext` varchar(6) NOT NULL,
`fac_fax` varchar(6) NOT NULL,
`gender` varchar(7) NOT NULL,
`newsletter_ok` enum('Y','N') DEFAULT 'Y',
`notes` varchar(300) NOT NULL,
`fac_type` varchar(14) NOT NULL,
`fac_contact_email` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
`ind_eng_bks_shipped` varchar(6) NOT NULL,
`ind_span_bks_shipped` varchar(6) NOT NULL,
`ind_eng_s_bks_shipped` varchar(6) NOT NULL,
`ind_span_s_bks_shipped` varchar(6) NOT NULL,
`indiv_other3_bks_shipped` varchar(6) DEFAULT '0',
`cases_eng_bks_shipped` varchar(6) DEFAULT '0',
`cases_span_bks_shipped` varchar(6) DEFAULT '0',
`cases_other1_bks_shipped` varchar(6) DEFAULT '0',
`cases_other2_bks_shipped` varchar(6) DEFAULT '0',
`cases_other3_bks_shipped` varchar(6) DEFAULT '0',
`last_update_by` varchar(20) NOT NULL,
`last_update_date` datetime NOT NULL,
`rev` varchar(9) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=3435 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 |
```

I removed the ---- stuff obviously.

Comment: Could you also include `show create table` output?

Comment: I should add I changed the in_add1, in_city, and in_state in my alter statement when I originally posted, but setting it to the proper values still gives me the same results (I assumed anyone reading this knows that).  Thanks

Comment: You have 2 or more rows with same values in the 3 columns (probably empty strings on all 3).

Comment: When I was manually correcting the DB, I kept running the alter statement above and it kept telling me the rows to fix.  When it was finally done complaining, I got that ERROR message.  I wrote a perl script and hashed the lower case of all 3 columns and find no duplicates there either.

Comment: My bad, I read the output wrong, I have a bunch, ugh.  Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you want to hunt down what key combinations are preventing the unique key from working, run this

```
SELECT add1, city, state,COUNT(1) rowcount
FROM mytable GROUP BY add1, city, state
HAVING COUNT(1) > 1;
```

To see the actual rows, run this

```
SELECT A.* FROM mytable A INNER JOIN
(SELECT add1, city, state,COUNT(1) rowcount
FROM mytable GROUP BY add1, city, state
HAVING COUNT(1) > 1) B USING (add1, city, state);
```

This will give you the opportunity to clean up the data

Alternatively, you may decide to make it a regular nonunique index.